# Mysql query get results if fields aren't equal

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
select a.*, ag.Winstpercentage from Artikels a 
inner join Artikelgroep ag on a.`Artgroep`=ag.Groepcode 
where a.`Manuf_nr` in (some array)
```

In this query I have `price` field. I need to compare `Manuf_nr` for all these fields, and if  it's same I need to check that `price` fields are not equal for rows who have same `Manuf_nr`. Anyone knows how to do this?

UPDATE:
field `price` is in `Artikels` table, so I select it under a.*
I changed my query so it looks like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Artikels` 
inner join (select * from Artikels) as totals 
        on Artikels.`Manuf_nr` = totals.`Manuf_nr` and 
           Artikels.`Vprijsexcl`!= totals.`Vprijsexcl` 
where Artikels.`Manuf_nr` in 
(select Manuf_nr from Artikels 
 group by Manuf_nr having count(*) >1)
```

but it takes too long. Anyone knows how to speed it up?
UPDATE: field `price` is field `Vprijsexcl`

This is what I have:

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egryk.png)

And I need to get all data where `Manuf_nr` is equal and `Vprijsexcl` are not equal.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why do you need results for this...

Comment: we can't see the price field in 'this query'. This question certainly needs more details.

Comment: you could join `Artikels` back to itself on a1.Manuf_nr = a2.Manuf_nr and a1.Price != a2.Price

Comment: How many rows do you have on your Artikels table? How long does your existing query take?

Comment: 35000... that's why it takes so long

Comment: actually I have 55000

Comment: **How long does your existing query take?**

Comment: The thing is that it doesn't get results... I let it doing his things for a few minutes but I don't get result

Comment: Refering to your table: What result (_exactly_) do you want for Manuf_nr ZP-501E, for which you have 3 rows with 2 different Vprijsexcl?

Comment: I want to get all data from table where `Manuf_nr` is same but `Vprijsexcl` are different. Example: for `ZP-501E` I want to get data where `Artikelnr` is `IPLSPE-CT00963321`

Comment: My edited query should give you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Artikels` 
inner join Artikels as totals 
        on Artikels.`Manuf_nr` = totals.`Manuf_nr` and 
           Artikels.`Vprijsexcl`!= totals.`Vprijsexcl`
```

- the `where ... in (subquery)` clause is redundant, because the main query can **only** return results from manufacturers that have more than one row in the Artikels table.

UPDATED: To see only the differing prices for the same manufacturer, try:

```
SELECT `Manuf_nr`, group_concat(distinct `Vprijsexcl`) prices
FROM `Artikels` 
GROUP BY `Manuf_nr`
HAVING count(distinct `Vprijsexcl`) > 1
```

Comment: can't get result from this query... or it takes more than few minutes ti get results

Comment: @MrCkobe: I have added a query that should be faster - how does it compare?

Comment: @MrCkobe: what datatype is `Vprijsexcl`? Do you still see a blob if you convert `Vprijsexcl` to a character field in the group_concat?

Comment: `Vprijsexcl` is float(8,2)

Comment: @MrCkobe: **Do you still see a blob if you convert Vprijsexcl to a character field in the group_concat?**

Comment: What do you mean by convert Vprijsexcl to a character field?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT Manuf_nr,  Vprijsexcl, COUNT (*)
FROM Artikels
GROUP BY Manuf_nr, Vprijsexcl
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

which lists the `Manuf_nr`, `Vprijsexcl` combinations that are not unique.

**EDIT:**

To get all information about the products which have a distinct `Vprijsexcl` for their `Manuf_nr`:

```
SELECT Artikels.* 
FROM Artikels
INNER JOIN (SELECT Manuf_nr,  Vprijsexcl, COUNT (*)
            FROM Artikels
            GROUP BY Manuf_nr, Vprijsexcl
            HAVING COUNT (*) = 1) AS A
USING (Manuf_nr, Vprijsexcl)
```

Comment: With this query I get only one row for each `Manuf_nr`, `Vprijsexc1` and I don't know is that `Vprijsexc1` value distinct than other `Vprijsexc1` field with same `Manuf_nr`

Comment: It gives you the `Manuf_nr, Vprijsexcl` combinations that are _not_ distinct. If you want to list the distinct ones, change `COUNT(*) > 1`to `COUNT(*) = 1`.

Comment: But the problem is that I need to check if `Manuf_nr` is same and then compare `Vprijsexcl` and then if `Vprijsexcl` are different I show it

Comment: Show (as a table) what you want your query results to look like.